# Ubuntu 19.04 Network issues

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet, ethernet

A day before I installed 19.04 in my HP laptop alongside Windows 10 (Dual boot).
I am experiencing the following issues -

**Wi-Fi issue:**
The Wi-Fi is not working. In Wi-Fi settings, it was showing 'No Wi-Fi adapter found'. After going through the Internet regarding this, I came to know that the HP Wi-Fi driver is not compatible with Ubuntu. A new driver was needed to be installed for that purpose. But this will be requiring an Internet connection obviously. So, I proceeded to set up a DSL connection but is facing issues in that too. Somehow managed to set up a DSL connection yesterday and tried to fix the issue as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbrYpqHadVQ) but still, the Wi-Fi is not working yet.

**DSL connection issue:**
I set a DSL connection as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAUXs3WLuug). But after clicking the connection name in Wired Connections list in Network Settings, the dialogue box for username and password does not appear most of the time unlike shown in the video and picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUjrW.png). Though it appeared once yesterday and I was able to connect the Internet after that, but today it is not appearing and so is unable to connect to the Internet.

**Network Manager issue:** Today in Network settings, it is showing the message - 'Network manager needs to be running'. I tried command - `/etc/init.d/network-manager start` and rebooted, still Network Manager is not working. Please find Network Manager status [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw36H.png).

Answer (score 0):

For the DSL connection, set it up like this: 
`nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "newconnection/whatever"
set pppoe.username ....
set pppoe.password ....
save
quit` 
Then:

 `nm-connection-editor` 
and disable "Automatically connect" for the Ethernet/Wired connection in the General tab. Then for the DSL/PPPOE connection, in the IPv6 settings tab, Method, select Ignore.
Then in the terminal: `sudo service network-manager restart`. It only works like this for me. In Ubuntu 18.04 I didn't have to do the ignore IPv6 thing.